# Hiding the intermediate table for the application layer

Tags: c#, .net-core, orm, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using entity framework 2.2.

I have a very basic setup: `User`, `UserRole`, `Role`.

Ideally, I would like to do operations like these: `User.Roles.Where(...)`. But I can't.
I have to pollute the application logic with data structure details, so I have to do something like this: `User.UserRoles.Where(x => x.Role...)`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I've tried to define an expression for finding the users with a specific role:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> HasRole(string role)
{
    return user => user.UserRoles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == role);
}
```

And call it like this:

```cs
var admins = await _context.Users
    .Where(User.HasRole("Admin"))
    .ToListAsync();
```

So that I don't need to know about the `UserRole` table.

I am aware that there's an open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1368) on github, but I was thinking what workarounds we could use for now?

I've seen another approach on the internet:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles => this.userRoles.Select(x => x.Role);
```

It would've been perfect if it could be automatically translated into Expression somehow, but I need to Include UserRoles before I can use `user.Roles`, which basically, doesn't solve my problem.